# Does a Java 8 fixed thread pool always create a fixed number threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I'm looking at code for the Java 8 fixed thread pool.  Here's a small sample:

```
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);

    try {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            service.submit(() -> "In another thread!");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Do nothing
    } finally {
        service.shutdown();
    }
```

The question I have is (in two parts):

a. How many threads will the fixed thread pool object above create?  100?  Or just 10?

b. How can I check how many threads have been created?

Answer (score 3):

> How many threads will the fixed thread pool object above create? 100? Or just 10?

It isn't specified. All that is specified is that there will never be more than 100.

> How can I check how many threads have been created?

There is no API for that. You could get the total thread count before and after, but that could be fuzzy as Java has other reasons for creating threads.

Comment: Thanks!  Looks like my question's been answered.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't make assumptions about how an executor will spin up underlying threads in your application code. Just to satisfy your curiosity:

> How many threads will the fixed thread pool object above create? 100? Or just 10?

Completely depends on the `ThreadFactory` used- by default, a fixed thread pool spawns threads lazily. Of course this may change in any subsequent JDK unless otherwise documented. As @EJP said, the only invariant you can rely on is there will be no more than 100 of them.

> How can I check how many threads have been created?

There's no way of getting threads dedicated to a particular executor, but from inside the JVM you can use [Thread#getAllStackTraces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getAllStackTraces()) to get a map of call stacks for all *live* threads. Alternatively use some tool like VisualVM.

Answer (score 0):

The following are two simple classes that I used as idioms to when learning the `ExecutorService`, `Callable`, and `Future` classes.

You can see that I use a thread pool of size 2, and have 10 items that I need to process. Basically, you create a thread pool, pass in classes that implement `Callable`, and use the resulting `Future` as proof of processing. Only two items can be processed at a time, given the thread pool of size 2. You can change the values if you'd like to see the results.

Main.java:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

        List<Future<String>> lst = new ArrayList<Future<String>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            Callable<String> callable = new Calling();
            Future<String> future = executorService.submit(callable);
            lst.add(future);
        }

        int futureCount = 0;
        for (Future<String> fut : lst) {
            try {
                futureCount++;
                System.out.println("Processed call() in thread " + fut.get() + ", future number: " + futureCount);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        executorService.shutdown();
        while (!executorService.isTerminated()) {
            // wait, basically
        }

        System.out.println("Finished all threads!");

    }
}
```

Calling.java

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

public class Calling implements Callable<String> {

    public Calling() {
    }

    public String call() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Sleeping thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        return Thread.currentThread().getName();
    }

}
```

Comment: If you're going to downvote my answer, explain why. I see no reason why my answer does not provide valuable context to help educate the OP.